# Jmeter UltimateTgreadGroup - How to set number of threads and load dynamically

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a set of dynamic parameters in Jmeter Ultimate thread Groups, which will be inserted from Jenkins.
Variables are set on Test Plan level and are definitely read and recognized:

- holdLoad: ${__P(holdLoad,240)}
- startupTime: ${__P(startupTime,30)}
- threadcount: ${__P(threadCount,25)}
- serverUrl, ....

Now in thread groups, I want to execute the following:

- StartThreadsCount = ${threadCount}
- Hold Load (sec): ${holdLoad}*10
- Initial Delay: ${startupTime}*4

Unfortunately this is not filled up correctly during execution. The Hold Load should multiply the value by 10 (or other depending on the row), but it actually runs in 10 seconds, ignoring the first part.
Other are treated same.

Is there any way to use such dynamic counts? Or does it always have to be a number?
UTG is very important for us, we are using stepping thread group for assessing the servers capabilities.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `${startupTime}*2` expression doesn't make sense as it's being interpreted into 30*2

If you want JMeter to evaluate the arithmetic expression you need to wrap it into a function which can interpret the expression, for example [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) is a good candidate:

```
${__jexl3(${startupTime}*2,)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: ***Thank you!*** That works!